# starting point for Web based Chat?

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, xmpp, chat

I am a junior developer and tryin to learn and immplement new stuff.

I am wondering how can I implemented a web based chat, just like "gmail chat".

How can I do this, what protocol is used and what shoudl be my starting point?

Regards
Adofo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend leveraging XMPP and using [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im) as your server. On the client side (web side), you could use the [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) library to "talk to" your ejabberd server. It is possibly the most active and up-to-date JavaScript library and the developers are usually available to help answer questions on their chatroom (Jabber: sleek@conference.jabber.org).

XMPP is the same protocol that Google chat, Facebook chat, etc. all use and integration with them is possible if desired. I can't recommend enough reading [XMPP: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521271) as a jumping off point for your project in order to fully understand the protocol.

Another book I recommend for the client (web) side is [Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery](http://professionalxmpp.com/), though some of the example code has minor typos.

Good luck!

Edit: Also, I should mention that "Jabber" and "XMPP" are used interchangeably very often in the chat world - so you don't get confused when you're starting out with your reading.

Answer (score 0):

For the backend, you can use [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) or any other jabber/xmpp server supporting BOSH. You could take a look at [jwchat](http://blog.jwchat.org/jwchat/) as an example for a frontend. Maybe you could even dive straight into the [jsjac](http://blog.jwchat.org/jsjac/) or [strophe](http://strophe.im/) libraries if you're feeling adventurous.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the response, it has certainly helped me.
May I ask if jwchat can talk to OpenFire server.
Regards

Comment: it looks like [Strophe](http://strophe.im/) might be able to do it: http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-xmpp-programming-javascript-jquery/81666-bosh-strophe-openfire.html